# Entity Framework Core 3 : Type must match overridden member

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following two dbcontexts in my Entity Framework Core solution. The `OrganisationContext` derives from  `SagitarriContext`. I am overiding the base property `DbSet<Person> Person`. I am getting the following error in the derived class:

> Error CS1715
>   'OrganisationContext.Person': type must be 'DbSet' to match overridden member 'SagitarriContext.Person'

DbContext

```
namespace Genistar.Data.DbContexts.Interfaces
{
    public class SagitarriContext : DbContext, ISagitarriContext
    {
        public SagitarriContext();
        public SagitarriContext(DbContextOptions<SagitarriContext> options);
        protected SagitarriContext(DbContextOptions options);

        public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }   
 }
```

```
 namespace Genistar.Data.DbContexts
 {
    public class OrganisationContext : SagitarriContext
    {
        private readonly ITimeProvider _timeProvider;
        private readonly IUserContextResolverFactory _userContextResolver;

        public OrganisationContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public OrganisationContext(DbContextOptions options, ITimeProvider timeProvider, IUserContextResolverFactory userContextResolver)
            : base(options)
        {
            _timeProvider = timeProvider;
            _userContextResolver = userContextResolver;
        }

        public override DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }       
}
```

```
 namespace Genistar.Data.DbContexts.Interfaces
    {
      public interface ISagitarriContext
      {
            Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
            DbSet<TQuery> Set<TQuery>() where TQuery : class;
            public DatabaseFacade Database { get; }

            DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Genistar.Data.DbContexts;
using Genistar.Data.Models;
using Genistar.Organisation.Models.Representative;
using Genistar.Organisation.Models.Unregistered;
using Genistar.Organisation.Models.User;
using Person = Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels.Person;
using PersonNote = Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels.PersonNote;

using Genistar.Security.Context;
using Genistar.Security.Utility;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the same namespace, so the `Person` class used in `DbSet<Person>` might be a different one in `Genistar.Data.DbContexts.Interfaces` and `Genistar.Data.DbContexts`. Also, we don't see the usings, so there might be an error there.

Comment: I have updated the post with my using statements as well as declaration of DbSet in the interface

Comment: This does not help very much. Which namespace does `Person` have?. Is there one `Person` class or are there several `Person` classes in different namespaces? If there is more than one `Person` class around, specify the usings separately for the `SagitarriContext` and `OrganisationContext` classes.